# Avoid flushing registers on memory access (gcc inline asm)

Tags: gcc, x86, inline-assembly

In the GCC manual, section [6.43.2.5 Extended Asm - Clobbers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/Extended-Asm.html), in the explanation of the "memory" clobber, a trick to avoid flushing registers is mentioned:

> If you know the size of the memory being accessed at compile time, you may specify a memory input like this:
>
> ```
> {"m"( ({ struct { char x[10]; } *p = (void *)ptr ; *p; }) )}
> ```
>
> (Assuming you access a string of 10 bytes.)

I think I understand the idea, but it is not entirely clear to me how to use it and what implications this trick has -- apart from giving more type information to GCC.
Most importantly three questions arise:

- May I also use this as an output or input/output operand and modify the data?
- If I use this trick, do I still need the "memory" clobber?
  I guess I don't, because I declared the chunk of memory as input/output, but I am unsure.
- Can I safely drop the `volatile` qualifier needed when only accessing memory?
  I guess I could, because it would be declared as output.

And since we like examples: Does this code make sense and is it legal? It seems to work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

void add_assembly(std::uint64_t * x) {
  struct memory { std::uint64_t data[2]; } * p = reinterpret_cast<memory*>(x);
  __asm__ (
        "addq $1, %[x] \t\n"
        "addq $5, 8%[x] \t\n"
        : [x] "+m" (*p) // Bonus question: Why don't I need a "&" here?
        : "m" (*p)
        : "cc"
  );
}

int main() {
  std::uint64_t x[2];
  x[0] = 3000;
  x[1] = 7253;
  std::cout << "before: " << x[0] << " " << x[1] << std::endl;
  add_assembly(&x[0]); // add 1 to x[0], add 5 to x[1]
  std::cout << "after:  " << x[0] << " " << x[1] << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about everything in this answer, but I did have a look at this issue myself recently.

> May I also use this as an output or input/output operand and modify the data?

Yes, but you might be better off with a separate `r`(register) or `m` (potentially a complex addressing-mode) constraint.  This is esp. true if you want to increment the pointer in a loop, and thus need it in a register.  An `m` constraint can make `%0` expand to `(%rsi, %rdx, 4)` or something.

> If I use this trick, do I still need the "memory" clobber?

No.  This tells gcc which memory is potentially modified.  `"memory"` means *all* memory is potentially modified.

> Can I safely drop the `volatile` qualifier needed when only accessing memory?

You mean `asm volatile (...)`?  Yes.  The `volatile` is only needed to get gcc to not move or eliminate an `asm` statement when the surrounding code doesn't use its outputs (or it doesn't have any).  As long as you tell gcc about the result your asm produces in memory, and use that result, you should not use `volatile`, so gcc can optimize like it could around any other black-box function.  (Assuming of course your asm is a "pure" function that only depends on its stated inputs.)

---

Examples are good. :)  Yours looks right.

I think you're right that specifying a read-write input operand isn't sufficient; you need to specify it twice, as input and output.  The wording of the `+` constraint made me think that "read and written" means that gcc considers the value you leave in it as the new value of the variable, but I think that's not the case.

I think on x86, the `m` constraint is equivalent to an `o` (offsettable) constraint.  But be careful about syntax; you don't want `8%[x]` to turn into `88(%rsp)`.  So maybe `8 + %[x]`?  Not sure.  At leave a space, so it's a syntax error instead of a different number.

`\t\n` is silly.  You want the tabs at the start of each line.

```
asm (
    "inc      %[x]   \n\t"   // inc is shorter than `add`
    "addq $5, 8 %[x] \n\t"   // this `add` writes all flags, preventing partial-flag stalls / slowdowns
    : [x] "+m" (*p) // Bonus question: Why don't I need a "&" here?
         // because you aren't writing a temporary to the output before reading the input
    : "m" (*p)
    : "cc"
);
```